# Type Assertion in Http Requests with HttpClient

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I'm migrating an Angular application to HTTPClient from the original HTTPModule. I am removing explicit parsing of JSON from my requests, but I have many instances below where Response.json() is asserted as a specific type. In these cases, is it safe for me to ignore this type assertion?

```
getCert(id: number, certId: number) {
  return this.http.get(certUrl(id, certId))
    .map(r => r.json() as UpdateCertViewModel);
}
```

Comment: On a side note you should also start using the [Pipeable Operators](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the body to this which uses the generic `get` overload that does the type assertion.

```
return this.http.get<UpdateCertViewModel>(certUrl(id, certId));
```